# Query with Criteria Exception error in doctrine2,Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I have a problem in symfony2 and doctrine2. When I add a Criteria exception, it doesn't appear like I want. This is the code:

Model

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="users",inversedBy="friends",cascade={"ALL"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="friends",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      )
 */
private $friendsof;

public function getusersre() {

    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->Where($criteria->expr()->eq('accepted', '1'));
    return $this->friendsof->matching($criteria);

}
```

Output

```
SELECT te.id AS id, te.email AS email, te.username AS username
FROM users te JOIN friends t ON t.user_id = te.id
WHERE t.friend_id = ? AND te.accepted = ?
```

I want that it appear like this:

```
WHERE t.friend_id = ? AND t.accepted = ?
```

Comment: Could you add `Users` entity code?

Comment: this is http://jpst.it/DkP7

Comment: Where is your `accepted` field?

Comment: No, I don't use the `accepted` field in the Users entity , I use it in the `Friend` entity : http://jpst.it/DkSm . 
I juste want to create a small social network , and in this stage I want to show user friends (Where the accepted row is true'1')
Thanks for care,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine generates intermediate table for `Many to Many` relationship. And you can't add any field to that table. I mean field `accepted`. Also you have three tables:

- Users.
- Intermediate table for many to many relationship.
- Friends.

In your `getusersre` function you want to try get friends. As I understood it is impossible to add `accepted` field for your criteria as you wanted.

Also I have changed your structure. What do you think about it?

```
class User
{

   /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
    */
   private $username;


   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Friend", mappedBy="userId")
    */
   private $friends;

   //Other fields, getters and setters.
}

class Friend
{
   /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friends")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
   protected $userId;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friends")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
   protected $friendId;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="accepted", type="boolean")
    */
   protected $accepted;

   //Other fields, getters and setters
}
```

The name of `Friend` entity is not solid. You can use `FriendRelationship`.

Also,function `getAcceptedFriends` will like that.

```
public function getAcceptedFriends()
{
    $cr = Criteria::create();
    $cr->andWhere($cr->expr()->eq('accepted', 1));

    return $this->friends->matching($cr);
}
```

Or

```
public function getAcceptedFriends()
{
    $friends = [];
    /** @var Friend $friend */
    foreach ($this->friends as $friend) {
        if ($friend->getAccepted()) $friends[] = $friend;
    }

    return $friends;
}
```

You can use like that.

```
foreach($user->getAcceptedFriends() in $friendRelationship){

   // $friendRelationship is a instance of Friend.
   $username = $friendRelationship->getFriendId()->getUsername();
}
```

In twig

```
{% for fr in user.acceptedFriends %}
    {{ fr.friendId.username }}
{% else %}
    {{ 'No friend' }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks alot , I'm sure that this is the right reponse .. But i still have a small problem :
The target-entity social\socialBundle\Entity\Friend cannot be found in 'social\socialBundle\Entity\users#friends

Comment: I prefer use capitalize letters for entities, controllers, services. About your problem, change all `Friend` to `friends`, `User` to `users`.

Comment: Really I'dont  know how to think you , But this Don't give the results of Users Table that i want to use in the view : http://jpst.it/Dk_3

.. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Updated the answer, your `user` variable is instance of `Friend`.

Comment: so , what should i do ?

Comment: @hassenzouari I have updated the answer. I suggest you have a function `getusersre` and you want to get user's friends? Then you can do like 

`{% for fr in user.getusersre %} {{ fr.friendId.username }}  {% endfor %}`

Comment: thanks , please can you add me on skype : hz4web    ....
because i still have some errors .
i'm really so Sorry for the inconvenience .